# Strange hotel addresses difference issue

Tags: hotels, italy, bookings

I am eager to know if someone beside me encounter this strange situation with hotels addresses.

I booked the hotel [Hotel Nettuno](http://www.booking.com/hotel/it/nettuno-de-charme.en-gb.html?aid=400000;sid=8f45787a5417a4fe5ed531414bdbe69f;dcid=1;dist=0;type=total) with address **Via Cesare Piro 1 I**, Forio di Ischia, 80075 Ischia on the booking.com site.
But when I got confirmation letter for my reservation the hotel name and address were Hotel Nettuno De Charme and **Via Cesotta 34**,Forio D'ischia, 80075, Italy. Just like on the picture below.
[image]

The funny part is when I click on the link of the hotel it leads to [Hotel Nettuno](http://www.booking.com/hotel/it/nettuno-de-charme.en-gb.html?aid=400000;sid=8f45787a5417a4fe5ed531414bdbe69f;dcid=1;dist=0;type=total). **I sent emails to booking.com support and hotel support twice, but there was no answer.** 
What could it be, is it booking.com bug or name of street where hotel is situated has changed? Or something else?

I forgot to mention that when I printed confirmation via booking.com. The address was like should be (**Via Cesare Piro 1 I**), but I still confused with e-mail difference.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply calling them?  And why would it matter?

Comment: I don't like this fuzziness when booking. My personal suggestion is to book another accomodation, if possibile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'other' address is for the Hotel Tritone and there is clearly some 'arrangement' between the two (ie see the logo at the bottom of this [page](http://www.hoteltritoneischia.it/)).

Comment: According to their site they're on Via Tommaso Cigliano, though. And Via Cesotta doesn't appear on Google Maps. Weird.